# Pinescript Hide Plotchar stats from Chart

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to hide the Plotchart stats that appear on the chart next to the script name? (marked by a red box in the picture)

*See on the picture enclosed:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. These items are in the chart settings.
[image]

Comment: Yes. Thanks so much. I wish there was a way to hardcode it in the script.

Comment: That possibility is not available in Pine (yet).